# MySQL installation on Red Hat Linux using SSH putty

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, installation, redhat

I have tried the following commands from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html) to install MySQL on the Red Hat Linux on remote server using Putty.

```
sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
```

this command ran succesfully.

Then running this command - `sudo yum install mysql-community-server`
, throwing this error -

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
itc                                                                                                                                              | 4.1 kB  00:00:00
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.mysql.com; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (MySQL Connectors Community),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable mysql-connectors-community

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=mysql-connectors-community.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from mysql-connectors-community: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.mysql.com; Unknown error"
```

Also when I run this-

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
```

Getting this error -

```
https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
Resolving repo.mysql.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “repo.mysql.com”
```

Can someone please help me resolving this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a relase series, and alterwards install mysql-community-server. Description [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html)

Comment: Followed the same description. But no luck. Can you be more specific on the release thing you are talking about?

Comment: Which RHEL are you use?

Comment: redhat-release-server-7.1-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: Look in the description to the Top 2: Selecting a Release Series. Enable with the yum-config-manager and than enable the repolist. Now you should be able to install with sudo yum install mysql-community-server. Short would it be: yum --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-community-server. If it's still not working, I would recommend to update to RHEL 7.4.

Comment: Its somewhat worked but with some error - http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 30387 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.

Comment: Is it the connection issue?? I am trying to install mysql on remote server using Putty.

Comment: I don't think so. I have no more idea